# find all paths under a directory

Tags: java, file, arraylist, directory

All I need to do is scan a directory (that could be containing sub-directories) and get a list of all the paths contained inside it.

EDIT: change the whole question to make it more specific!

Comment: `Files.walkFileTree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt would be:

```
    try {
        List<Path> pathsInDir = new ArrayList<>();

        // Dir to scan
        DirectoryStream<Path> newDirectoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("."));

        for(Path path : newDirectoryStream) {
            if(Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                pathsInDir.add(path);
                // recursive call to scan sub dir
            } else {
                // handle files.
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO please handle the exception.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can use the methods of *java.nio.file.Path* to compare the directory names.

Comment: Please [don't use the `File` class anymore](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). It's outdated and uninformative. Use the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class instead.

Comment: thanks works great after a small change! check the edit

Comment: Sorry, i rejected the edit ;). Hope you don't mind. I think this one solves either problems...

Comment: my bad.. What your code does is not what I need it to do but it does what my question asks :p Fixed it anyway though so it's accepted!